# apply css class to a div without js

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am displaying some nested comments recursively in my app but ran into a challenge of apply a specific class when there are no nested comments. How can I cleanly apply the class `sole` to my div `entry` only when nested_commments is > 0 ?

```
    def horizontal_tree_for(comments)
        comments.map do |comment, nested_comments|
       entry(comment) + 
          (nested_comments.size > 0 ?          
              content_tag(:div, horizontal_tree_for(nested_comments), class: "branch") +
            "</div>"

          : "</div>")
    end.join.html_safe
  end

def entry(comment)
  "<div class='entry'  **conditional sole class**><span class='label'> #{comment.name} </span>"
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to simply write the class? Pseudo: `"<div class='entry (nested_comments.size > 0 ? "sole" : "")'><span class='label'> #{comment.name} </span>"`

Comment: @rabelloo that works ! you can put it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, simply write the class.

Pseudo-code:

```
"<div class='entry (nested_comments.size > 0 ? "sole" : "")'>
 <span class='label'> #{comment.name} </span>"
```

Answer (score 0):

This style only the elements that have children:

```css
.empty {
        background-color:black;
        height: 100px;  
}
div:not(:empty) {
        background-color:red !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="empty"></div>
<div class="empty">
    <div> </div>
    <div> </div>
</div>
```